# i moved opencart on another domain and error ini_set() is disable

Tags: php, function, opencart

i moved opencart website on another server, but i am receiving following errors.

```
Warning: ini_set() has been disabled for security reasons in /home/shoppin6/public_html/system/library/session.php on line 7Warning: ini_set() has been disabled for security reasons in /home/shoppin6/public_html/system/library/session.php on line 8Warning: ini_set() has been disabled for security reasons in /home/shoppin6/public_html/system/library/session.php on line 9Warning: ini_set() has been disabled for security reasons in /home/shoppin6/public_html/system/library/session.php on line 10Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /home/shoppin6/public_html/index.php:102) in /home/shoppin6/public_html/system/library/session.php on line 21
```

ive edited php.ini file with this

```
disable_functions = allow_url_fopen, escapeshellarg, escapeshellcmd, ini_alter, passthru, parse_ini_file, popen, proc_open, proc_close, proc_terminate, proc_get_status, proc_nice, readfile, show_source, system
```

and also i seted ini_set = on; php.ini file, but error are same, there is no changes in errors, here is website link, shoppingdice.com

Please give me the solution quick please

Comment: VPS or Shared host ?

Comment: its shared hosting

Comment: The only one that can do anything about this is your server admin.  You should talk to your hosting company.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally you would need to restart the web server service for the changes in php.ini to take effect. However that may not be applicable on shared hosting if you don't have control of your own web server process. If you can restart the service (and didn't already do it after changing php.ini) then I suggest you do that.

If still having problems you might want to take a look at the output of the following (you can put it a page like test.php) and then recall that page in a browser:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
```

It should show the location of the php configuration under "Loaded Configuration File" and hopefully that will be the one you changed. Under the "Core" section you should be able to see the value of "disable_functions". If it is not the value you set, then your changes were not effective. For security reasons delete the file test.php once you've finished debugging the issue.